# R and SQL how to download only matched ids?

Tags: sql, r

I have this dataframe in R.

```
df <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at  
1            107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
2            107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
3            107 2017-11-28 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
4            109 2016-11-28 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
5            109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
6            110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07", header=TRUE)
```

I'm using this script for getting data from db, but I don't need load whole database just because of 3 ids.

```
get_data <- dbGetQuery(con_ff_ba, "SELECT id FROM db")
```

Is there a way how to load only that that data that matches id from df? That means id 107, 109, 110.

edit: The df is huge in reality and its not possible to fill all ids manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use `RODBCext` for this circumstance.

```
library(RODBCext)

conn <- odbcConnect(...) # edit as needed to form your connection

Result <- 
  sqlExecute(conn,
             "SELECT var1, var2, var3 
              FROM table 
              WHERE idvar = ?",
             idvar = df["id"],
             fetch = TRUE,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`sqlExecute` will internally perform a `for` loop that runs the query for each unique value of `df$id` and bind all of the results into a single data frame.

As an alternative, you can use `dplyr` in the following manner

```
library(dplyr)

tbl(conn, "table") %>%
  filter(idvar %in% df$id) %>%
  select(var1, var2, var3) %>%
  collect()
```

Comment: Is it possible with that dplyr solution join more tables and have some other criteria like select * from t1, left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id where column2 is not null and column3 = '23'

Comment: Yes, but it requires a `tbl` call to each table in the database.  It also requires that you retain any values you merge on in the intermediary.  I've tried to go about this a few times, and ultimately, I feel like doing joins through `dplyr` ends up making messy code.  If I have even a simple join, I'll generally use raw SQL and `dbGetQuery`.

Comment: Can I use that "odbcConnect(...)" for my postgres msql db?